# PHP code gets commented out

Tags: php, html

I have the following problem within the following script

PHP code:

```
$var = file_get_contents('template/default/index.php');
$content1 = str_replace('{php}','<?php',$var);
$content2 = str_replace('{/php}','?>',$content1);
echo $content2;
```

template/default/index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
      {php} echo 'worked'; {/php}
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to transform the {php}{/php} tags within the template/default/index.php to propper php tags. This actually happends, but the php code gets commented out. The browser gives this in return:

```
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<!--?php echo 'worked'; ?-->
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: are you using wordpress? any framework?

Comment: check the **template/default/index.php** content; the comment must be there.

Comment: Echoing the PHP like that isn't going to execute it, it would just send the PHP code to the browser, which will just display it. I would guess the Apache or PHP engine is commenting out the PHP code when you echo it. You'll need to either include the file or use the eval function.

Comment: Echo'ing will print as is, you need to eval it

Comment: sounds like happy code injections day =)

Comment: @AbaniMeher no I'm not using any framework or CMS

Answer (score 7):

Instead of echoing out the replaced content, it should be `eval`'d. Although I don't recommend that.

Comment: And how would I do that? Can;t figure it out with eval. Thanks for helping!

Comment: or use include, and capture via php output buffers: `ob_start(); include($file); $contents = ob_end_clean();`

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason to do any of this.

Just use `<?php` and `?>` in your index.php file instead of `{php}` and `{/php}` and then just include the file in your script.

Comment: I think he's trying to eval it like a template file similar to how Smarty template engine does it

Comment: Ehhhh I do not like it... @Kieran